# angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I am observing this error while trying to implement "ngRoute". Please help me fix this

```
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=mainApp&p1=TypeErro…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.3%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A379)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4920
    at p (angular.js:402)
    at g (angular.js:4880)
    at eb (angular.js:4802)
    at c (angular.js:1909)
    at Pc (angular.js:1930)
    at ue (angular.js:1815)
    at angular.js:33340
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3435)
```

Answer (score 0):

this looks familiar.. This means somewhere you have a module dependency declared that angular can't resolve. If its angular route you probably have this:
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','otherModule'])
and you are forgetting to add script tag for angular-route.js or to add it to your bundle ( if you are using grunt/gulp etc to build your app ). Bottom line is that it doesn't recognize a module you have specified as a dependency